# ... operator in function

Tags: c++11

Sorry for the noob question. I've been immersed in Java for the past while and the book for this course doesn't cover C++.

I have to fill in a function to add keywords (of string type) to an `Item` object. the prototype of the function is as follows.

```
 void addKeywordsForItem(const Item* const item, int nKeywords, ...);
```

In Java `...` returns the remainder of arguments as a `String` object and I'm guessing C++ does something similar but I don't know the name of `...` so searching for it is rather difficult.

What is `...` called and what does it do?

Comment: this ... is [variadic arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments), `catch(...)` means catch all handler, and it also means variadic template and its expansion

Comment: You have two unrelated questions. Please pick one. You can post your other question separately.

Comment: Okay, for the `...`, the answer you got is right, but now that you know what to search for, please be sure to also read up on why you generally shouldn't use variadic functions in modern C++, in particular the lack of type safety. If you want to get a set of strings, the basic type-safe approach uses `void addKeywordsForItem(const Item* const item, std::initializer_list<std::string> keywords)` (to be called as `addKeywordsForItem(item, {"a", "b", "c"})`), but more advanced approaches that allow more variation in how you call the function are possible as well.

Comment: Coming from Java I was wondering about that exact thing @hvd , I'll do that instead in the future. varargs was a part of the starter code and is at least implicitly required this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is `...` called and what does it do?

There are multiple places where `...` is used in C++. The context in which you are using it, it is called [`variadic arguments`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments).

The standard header [`cstdarg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdarg) provides a type and macros to help you extract specific arguments from variadic arguments.

Example code from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_start:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

int add_nums(int count, ...) 
{
    int result = 0;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        result += va_arg(args, int);
    }
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << add_nums(4, 25, 25, 50, 50) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Wow, I wish the teacher had made a note of that. Maybe add the example code here to your answer for someone else that looks at this?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_start